# Plot digitizer that overlays screen

Tags: graphs

When reading electronics datasheets, I often have to read values off charts that have sparse gridlines. I can save a screenshot of the chart using [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/), then input the image to [WebPlotDigitizer](https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/), click on the corners of the graph, say whether they're linear or logarithmic axes, and click a point on the graph to get the actual value of the point along that line (or digitize the entire graph so I can use it in a spreadsheet).

[image]

I've also used things like [Meazure](http://www.cthing.com/Meazure.asp), an overlay screen ruler, when I just want to read one point.  It lets you drag around points, showing a zoomed-in pixel view for accuracy, and measures the distance between them in various units.  For graphs I have to manually calculate the proportions to get the actual value, though.

[image]

Is there anything that combines these concepts, with a screen ruler overlay that I can click the 4 corners of a chart and then just read points off it in the graph's units, without having to take screenshots, open files, etc?

Comment: I was just going to ask this question again and saw that I had already asked it :(